# How to write CMakeFile when the code use C++, but called python

Tags: python, c++, linux, makefile, cmake

I have a C++ project with a CMakeFile which works ok before.

Now i write a new class in C++ but calling python to run. I kown how to write a MakeFile to build the single C++ with python, but what makes me confused is how to write the CMakeFile according to my project.

Here comes my MakeFile with single class:

```
outxx:
    g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/ pu.h pu.cpp main.cpp -lpython2.7 -o outxx -g
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.pyc  outxx
```

The pu class written by C++ but calling python. I kown the CMakeFile will compile to MakeFile and then compile the source code.

How to intergate the new Class's MakeFile into my odl CMakeFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)

add_executable(outxx main.cpp pu.cpp)
target_link_libraries(outxx ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(outxx PUBLIC ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

And if we were to try and run this:

```
[2:28pm][wlynch@watermelon blah] cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 6.1.0.6020053
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 6.1.0.6020053
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.6") 
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/blah


[2:29pm][wlynch@watermelon blah] make VERBOSE=1
/Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -H/tmp/blah -B/tmp/blah --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /tmp/blah/CMakeFiles /tmp/blah/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/depend
cd /tmp/blah && /Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /tmp/blah /tmp/blah /tmp/blah /tmp/blah /tmp/blah/CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/build
/Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /tmp/blah/CMakeFiles 1
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/main.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers    -o CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/main.o -c /tmp/blah/main.cpp
/Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /tmp/blah/CMakeFiles 2
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/pu.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers    -o CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/pu.o -c /tmp/blah/pu.cpp
Linking CXX executable outxx
/Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/main.o CMakeFiles/outxx.dir/pu.o  -o outxx  /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib 
/Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /tmp/blah/CMakeFiles  1 2
[100%] Built target outxx
/Users/wlynch/Homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /tmp/blah/CMakeFiles 0
```